# Discord.js V12 Rude words filter not working

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

so I am adding like a rude words filter, whenever someone says that word (lowercase or uppercase) it deletes their message and replies back with something and then the reply gets deleted in a few seconds.

Here's my current code, but it doesn't read the `rudeWords` and doesn't do anything when I write any of the rude words in the chat.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let rudeWords = ["kys", "kill yourself"];
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === rudeWords) {
        message.delete()
        message.reply('do not use that word here, thank you.').then(msg => {
        msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
    })
}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rudeWords` is an array, not a string so you can't compare `message.content` to `rudeWords` by checking if they're equal, instead, you need to use `includes()`

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let rudeWords = ["kys", "kill yourself"];
    if (rudeWords.includes(message.content.toLowerCase())) {
        message.delete()
        message.reply('do not use that word here, thank you.').then(msg => {
        msg.delete({ timeout: 3000 })
    })
}})
```

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to SO, if an answer solves your issue then please accept it to let others know what worked and that the question has been answered.

Comment: I will, it said I need to wait 8 minutes for some reason..
edit: 5 more