# Words filter stopped working - Discord.JS 12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

*Hello!*

So I'm currently updating my bot to version 12.3.1 of DiscordJS. Unfortunately, I got stuck on a problem that I can't really find a workaround. So, my bot has a module to filter out all of the bad words, like profanity, racial slurs, etc.

It's currently working just fine on 11.4, but cannot get it to work on 12.3.1
For some reason, the bot just does not react at all to given message.

I had two "filters" one for words, one for invites. Both of them stopped working.

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {

// Events Listeners

if (message.author.bot) return;
if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

let messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
let command = messageArray[0];
let args = messageArray.slice(1);

if (!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;

let cmd = bot.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length)) || bot.aliases.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
if (cmd) cmd.run(bot, message, args);

// First filter
var array = ['testing', 'yes', 'no'];

    if (array.includes(message.content.toLocaleLowerCase())) {

        message.channel.send('test')
    
    }



// Second filter
    if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/') { 

      message.delete()

    }

}
```

That's the current one I found from another StackOverflow post, made 2 months ago.
[Discord.js V12 Rude words filter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62501455/discord-js-v12-rude-words-filter-not-working)

I'd really love to get some help if possible, as I can't find any reason why this feature has stopped working.

*Thank you!* :)

Comment: You haven't actually shared the code for either of your filters... the snippet you do have doesn't seem to be in your message listener, and will only work on exact matches, i.e. a message containing a bad word and nothing else. Please edit in your original filters to the question so we may tell what made them stop working.

Comment: @Klaycon - Edited the message as requested. The filter is in the message => {}, as it's working on my current bot.
I simply don't understand why message.content.includes stopped working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filters are after your command handling logic.

You have the line:

```
if (!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;
```

early in your code, and this causes message handling to terminate immediately on any message which is not a command. Due to this, the code will never reach your filters unless the message starts with your bot's prefix, at which point the message content cannot possibly be equal to any of the words and is extremely unlikely to contain `discord.gg/`.

Simply move your filters to the beginning of your message handler. Or alternatively separate the command handling and filter handling into separate functions, so that the `return` statement above only exits the command handling and the filter handling will still run.

Comment: It fixed the issue! Thank you very much for your help. As I've mentioned, it works just fine in my current 11.4 bot, and I had no clue why it stopped working in 12.

Comment: @SilentWatcher More than likely while converting the bot you either fixed a bug with that if-statement, moved it to a new location, or otherwise changed the logic flow somehow. You could drop this exact code back into v11.4 and it would have exactly the same issue